# Find the process which is taking maximum CPU usage if CPU usage is more than 60%?

Tags: shell-script, performance, top

I am trying to measure the cpu usage of my ubuntu machine and if the cpu usage is more than 60%, then I need to find out the process who has the highest cpu usage and then send out an email saying CPU usage is more than 60% and with the process name which has the highest cpu usage.

When I do top this is what I see.

```
Cpu0  :  20.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  34.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  17.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  20.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

I came up with the below script which only finds out the cpu load but not the cpu usage. How do I achieve above thing?

```
#!/bin/bash

top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}'
```

To send an email, I use below command and it works for me -

```
echo "Body" | mailx -r "david@host.com" -s "SUBJECT" "david@host.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using awk:

```
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR==1{print $2,$3,$11}NR>1{if($3!=0.0) print $2,$3,$11}' > some_file.txt
```

the above code will give all program with non-zero cpu usage.
 will give you `pid,%cpu, command_name`

if you want cpu usage greater than equal to 60 replace `$3!=0.0` to `$3>=60`

I have saved the output in file `some_file.txt`. you can `cat` the file and pipe it to mail command.

try like this: to send mail

```
cat some_file.txt | mailx -r "david@host.com" -s "SUBJECT" "david@host.com"
```

Comment: if you wan  any modification you can ask me

Comment: thanks a lot hackaholic for the help. How can pipe this thing to my mailx commnad so that it can send out an email if any process has CPU usage greater than 60%?

Comment: @user2809564 I have edited the code as per your requirement hope that will help.